# asp.net custom control can't find code behind in web site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls

Firstly, this project type is a website.

I have a custom control(.ascx) which I use in different projects where the projecttype is an application.

But when I copy the files that make up my customcontrol to a project of type "web site" the .ascx file cant find the .ascx.vb file. Also when using the control in a web application there are 3 files in use: .ascx, .ascx.vb and .ascx.designer.vb and vs automatically groups these files togheter as if they belong to eachother. But in the website VS only groups .ascx and .ascx.vb. The designer file is not grouped to the other. ascx files as if this is not needed.

The .ascx looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="popupCalendarInterval.ascx.vb" Inherits="myCustomControls.popupCalendarInterval" %>
<asp:label ID="LabelStart" runat="server">
```

and code behind as follows:

```
Namespace myCustomControls
    Partial Class popupCalendarInterval
        Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

        Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            LabelStart.Text = ""
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

And then LabelStart is not recogniced though in an web application it is.

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you modify the ascx file? I usually don't see ~/ in the codebehind

Comment: yes. my bad. a leftover from when i tried to fix it.